# What is equivalent of onDraw in iOS

Tags: android, ios

On android we have onDraw(). What is the equivalent in iOS ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want `drawRect:`, though depending on what you want in your view there might be other options of interest (subviews & Core Animation layers). See the [View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing a custom view, it's basically `-drawRect:` which gets called on the view every time the system wants to redraw (e.g., every time the runloop turns and `-setNeedsDisplay` flag is set.

Answer (score 0):

you override the `-drawRect` method of a `UIView` to do direct drawing to the screen. However this isn't commonly needed for lots of use cases. If you want, provide more detail about what you want to achieve. There may be a more iOS way.